# How to update other components on transfering contents of primefaces picklist?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces-3.0.RC1-SNAPSHOT pickList. I want to invoke some function on transfering any item from source to target and vice versa so as to update the contents of another picklist.

I tried by adding

```
valueChangeListener="#{myBean.refreshList}"
```

In **refreshList()** I add the contents to a list which is set as **value** for the other pickList whose contents are to be updated and the **autoupdate** attribute of **p:outputPanel** which contains the second pickList is set as true.

But I have to invoke the function by some other means (using a commandButton etc) to update the second pickList. How can I update the second pickList without doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> transfering any item from source to target and vice versa

does not submit the form to server.

> valueChangeListener="#{myBean.refreshList}"

executes only when the form is submitted to the server and the value of component (in your case the 'picklist') has actually changed.

So, what you need to do is - submit it every time the transferring takes place.

You can use the `onTransfer` attribute of the PickList.